# Convert string to int in JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a class with a field "price" type integer and the filed has an annotation @Type("integer"). When in the request the param "price" comes with a string (the user put a string instead of a integer), JMS Serializer (PHP do it too) transform this value (string value) to zero (0) and as zero is a integer the validator don't check this param and always is zero.

Someone knows a config to JMS Serializer to don't convert a string to zero (0). Or any one else solutions.

```
/**
* @JMS\Type("integer")
* @var int
*/
private $price;
```

Comment: When you say "string value", what is the actual value? Is it numeric?

Comment: Can you share which symfony constraints are applied on the price field please?

Comment: I want to control that this field cannot contain a string like "asdasd" only numbers like 12.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the constraint on the field like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
* @Assert\Type("integer")
* @var int
*/
private $price;
```